# How can I wait for all promises to resolve before returning all their values?

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I'm using `Promise.map` from bluebird. I'm trying to wait for all promises to resolve before dispatching an event that contains an array of objects.

```js
readFiles() {
    const fileArray = Array.from(this.fileSelectInput.files)
    const promises = []

    window.Promise.map(fileArray, (file, index) => {
      return window.jsmediatags.read(file, {
        onSuccess: tag => {
          promises.push({
            id: index + 1,
            title: tag.tags.title || undefined,
            artist: tag.tags.artist || undefined
          })
          promises.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id)
          console.log('I should be first')
        }
      })
    }).then(() => {
        console.log('I should be second')
        this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('tracks-selected', {
          detail: promises
        }))
      }
    }
```

I'm running into the problem where `I should be second` is printed to the console before `I should be first`. the `detail: promises` dispatched by the event contains an empty array.

Comment: does `window.jsmediatags.read` return a Promise? if not, then there's no Promise to wait for

Comment: You should not store an array of `promises` when using `Promise.map`. You should return a promise for each iteration result from the callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for

```
const fileArray = Array.from(this.fileSelectInput.files);

window.Promise.map(fileArray, file => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    window.jsmediatags.read(file, {
      onSuccess: resolve,
      // also pass reject as an error handler if jsmediatags supports that
    });
  });
}).then(tags => {
  const results = tags.map(tag => ({
    id: index + 1,
    title: tag.tags.title || undefined,
    artist: tag.tags.artist || undefined
  }));
  // results.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id) - not necessary given .map() keeps the order
  this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('tracks-selected', {
    detail: results
  }))
});
```

Comment: This is it. I was forgetting to return a new Promise to Promise.map